# How to hide navigation bar at specific condition without animation in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want hide navigation bar at specific condition's. I am setting `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar` as false for hide and set true for visible navigation bar but there is an animation which will appear in xamarin ios. 
I want to remove that animation while hide and show navigation bar.

Comment: try to set it before you navigate to the screen

Comment: maybe need custom renderer.